# Zend Error: Registry is already initialized

Tags: zend-framework

So here's the situation:
-I have a forum software, XenForo for customers to frolick about in
-I have a membership software, aMember, to handle customer payments and deliver digital products. (Both on the same website)

aMember has a template system that allows you to (ideally) easily customize the script to look like it's naturally part of your website.

XenForo has a script addon that lets you use the customized XenForo Header and footer using a PHP "include" function.

So essentially, I can take a regular php file, call the XenForo header and footer using php include, and make that page look like it's part of the forum software (almost like a wordpress header/footer).  So far, everything I've mentioned is tested and working outside the aMember system, so I currently have an index.php file that calls the XenForo header and footer using include and it works great.

Here's where it gets nasty, I tried to use the PHP include script inside the aMember template system.  I got it mostly working, but then the following Error is thrown with the resulting fun batch of code afterwards:

```
Error: Registry is already initialized
Exception Zend_Exception
Zend_Registry::setClassName [ /home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/forum/library/XenForo/Application.php : 244 ]
XenForo_Application::initialize [ /home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/forum/library/Dark/Kotomi/KotomiHeader.php : 5 ]
include_once [ /home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/header.php : 6 ]
include_once [ library/Am/View.php : 419 ]
Am_View->printLayoutHead [ application/default/themes/sample/layout.phtml : 8 ]
include [ library/Am/View.php : 352 ]
Am_View->_run [ library/Zend/View/Abstract.php : 888 ]
Zend_View_Abstract->render [ library/Am/View.php : 326 ]
Am_View->display [ application/default/controllers/IndexController.php : 7 ]
IndexController->indexAction [ library/Am/Controller.php : 139 ]
Am_Controller->_runAction [ library/Am/Controller.php : 116 ]
Am_Controller->dispatch [ library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php : 295 ]
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch [ library/Zend/Controller/Front.php : 954 ]
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch [ library/Am/App.php : 1372 ]
Am_App->run [ index.php : 41 ]
```

From what I can tell and my limited programming knowledge, it looks like aMember and XenForo are having a fight over who gets to use the Zend Registry.

Is there anyway I can make them play well together without hiring a full time programmer for 6 months? Thanks so much!

........................................................Response to comment:

The add comment didn't have enough charecters, so here's some of the code.

From what I can tell XenForo uses it as it's primary..well...everything, here's the START of Application.php, part of XenForo's source code.  This file is over 1,000 lines, all of which make up the class that start's at the top...  This seems to be the only file that uses the Zend_Registry that isn't part of the Zend source itself.

```
class XenForo_Application extends Zend_Registry
{
const URL_ID_DELIMITER = '.';
public static $version = '1.1.0';
public static $versionId = 1010070; // abbccde = a.b.c d (alpha: 1, beta: 3, RC: 5, stable: 7, PL: 9) e
public static $jsVersion = '';
public static $jQueryVersion = '1.5.2';
protected $_configDir = '.';
protected $_rootDir = '.';
protected $_initialized = false;
protected $_lazyLoaders = array();
protected static $_handlePhpError = true;
protected static $_debug;
protected static $_randomData = '';
protected static $_classCache = array();
public static $time = 0;
public static $host = 'localhost';
```

aMember uses it across several files, here are a few examples:

This is inside form.php...

```
public function findRuleMessage(HTML_QuickForm2_Rule $rule, HTML_QuickForm2_Node $el)
    {
        $strings = array(
            'rule.required' => ___('This is a required field'),
        );
        $type = lcfirst(preg_replace('/^.+rule_/i', '', get_class($rule)));
            $tr = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
        $fuzzy = sprintf('rule.%s', $type);
        if (array_key_exists($fuzzy, $strings))
            return $strings[$fuzzy];
    }
```

And this is inside app.php....

```
function amDate($string) {
    if ($string == null) return '';
    return date(Zend_Registry::get('Am_Locale')->getDateFormat(), amstrtotime($string));
}
function amDatetime($string) {
    if ($string == null) return '';
    return date(Zend_Registry::get('Am_Locale')->getDateTimeFormat(), amstrtotime($string));
}
function amTime($string) {
    if ($string == null) return '';
    return date(Zend_Registry::get('Am_Locale')->getTimeFormat(), amstrtotime($string));
}
```

Alright, I better not post any more source code or they'll send the men in black after me.

It looks like it might be easier to program it out of aMember, but this is quickly looking like an insurmountable task, especially at my (lack of) skill level.

Additional Info:

```
public static function initialize($configDir = '.', $rootDir = '.', $loadDefaultData = true)
{
(244)self::setClassName(__CLASS__);
self::getInstance()->beginApplication($configDir, $rootDir, $loadDefaultData);
}
```

Commenting out Line 244 produced the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Registry::beginApplication() in /home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/forum/library/XenForo/Application.php on line 245
```

And adding the code you suggested into the aMember index.php file produced this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'XenForo_Application' not found in /home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/amember/index.php on line 40
```

Comment: How do you use Zend_Registry? Can you paste some code?

Comment: From my (limited) research, it doesn't seem like there would be a problem with the zend_registry holding variables from both softwares.  It seems the conflict comes when each script wants it's own zend_registry to play with, but they gotta share one.  If that's true, the question then becomes how can I get them both to drop their variables into the same Zend_Registry.  Get one to initialize and the other to just drop it's stuff into the same registry.

Answer (score 0):

What is on line `244` of `/home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/forum/library/XenForo/Application.php`? If it's just `Zend_Registry` which is the default class name and if you are not afraid of modifying the sources, just comment out the call on line `244`. But this is not advised as you would have problems if you wanted to update XenForo in the future.

Check if whatever is passed to `setClassName()` on line `244` can be configured somehow. Paste some more code. Get some more answers.

### UPDATE

Fighting with XenForo would probably require quite a lot of coding, so I'd suggest a rather different approach. Since aMemeber seems to use vanilla `Zend_Registry`, you can try to make sure `XenForo`'s extended version of `Zend_Registry` instantiates first. In your `index.php` (probably located in `public` directory) locate the line with `$application->bootstrap();` or similar, and **before** this line add something like this:

```
XenForo_Application::setClassName("XenForo_Application");
```

And comment out line `244` of `/home/content/p/p/o/ppowers/html/forum/library/XenForo/Application.php`.

If this works, remember to comment on the change, cross-referencing both modified files.

Comment: Here is the class that is on line 244:

(242)public static function initialize($configDir = '.', $rootDir = '.', $loadDefaultData = true)
(243){
(244)self::setClassName(__CLASS__);
(245)self::getInstance()->beginApplication($configDir, $rootDir, $loadDefaultData);
(246)}

How would you configure that so that it doesn't throw the error? By the way thanks a million for the help.

Comment: It would make more sense to paste the code into your original post and update, formatting will make it easier to read. You need to do some more debugging. For starters - what does the constant `CLASS` evaluate to? Where is it defined?

Comment: Looking through the code, it looks like it pulls from that class for tons of major functions like calling what threads to view and the like.  Also, I added the code to the top section....

I wonder if I could just add an 'if/then' statement in one or both of the scripts to prevent the double initialization of the registry.

I'm not concerned with upgrade issues, I just want the stuff to work....

Comment: Tried both of your recommendations and posted the results above.  Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Is this a modular ZF application? Can you post the directory structure? Is there more than one point of entry (`index.php`)? The second error is a simple case of class not being found, you should either have an autoloader for it or just `require_once`. The first error results from `setClassName` not being called, which you should enforce in `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I build my website I am using Zend framework v1.5: http://www.panpic.vn (**) | 
Forum using xenforo: http://www.panpic.vn/forum (*)

at homepage (**) I am Authentication User Xenforo
My Coding:

```
define('XF_ROOT', '/home/www/lighttpd/my_web/forum'); // set this (absolute path)!
define('STARTTIME', microtime(true) );
define('SESSION_BYPASS', false); // if true: logged in user info and sessions are not needed
require_once(XF_ROOT . '/library/XenForo/Autoloader.php');
XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader(XF_ROOT . '/library');
XenForo_Application::initialize(XF_ROOT . '/library', XF_ROOT);
XenForo_Application::set('page_start_time', STARTTIME );
XenForo_Application::setDebugMode(false);

if (!SESSION_BYPASS)
{

$dependencies = new XenForo_Dependencies_Public();
$dependencies->preLoadData();
$session =  XenForo_Session::startPublicSession(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http);
    XenForo_Visitor::setup($session->get('user_id'));

    $visitor = XenForo_Visitor::getInstance();    

    if ($visitor->getUserId())
    {
        $userModel = XenForo_Model::create('XenForo_Model_User');
        $userinfo = $userModel->getFullUserById($visitor->getUserId());        
    }

}
```

**Error**: Registry is already initialized

Could you how do I fix ?